# JavaScript function performs differently when viewing the page at the URL than when viewing the page in a browser locally

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have the following web page, which displays a number of images and a 'score bar' on an HTML5 canvas:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  canvas{
    border: 1px solid #9C9898;
    background:#F5F5F5;
  }
</style>
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="kinetic.js"></script>
<script src="drawdescriptionboxes.js"></script>
<script src="drawLevelOneElements.js"></script>
<script src="startGameDrawGameElementsDrawStartButton.js"></script>
<script>
/*Add the game elements' global variables */
var currentLevel = 1;
var totalLevels = 3;
var currentScore = 0;
var currentScorePositionX = 950;
var currentScorePositionY = 10;

/*Add code to draw images to random locations here */
    var imageX = Math.floor(Math.random()*950);
    var imageY = Math.floor(Math.random()*450);

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: "container",
      width: 1000,
      height: 500
    });
    var imagesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var canvas = imagesLayer.getCanvas();
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    console.log("Foo ");

/*Load the images from the HTML into the JavaScript */
function loadImages(sources, callback){
    var imagesDir = "";
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;

    //console.log("length " + sources.length);
    for (var src in sources){
        numImages++;
    }
    //console.log("Num Images " + numImages);

    var index=0;
    console.log("length " + sources.length);
    for (index=0;index < numImages ;index++){
        console.log(index);
        images[index] = new Image();
        images[index].src = sources[index];
        console.log("Adding " + sources[index]);
        callback(images[index]);
        console.log("images array length = " + images.length);
    }

    stage.add(imagesLayer); // should only be added once!!
}

/*Function to check whether the item being dragged is near its description box */
function isNearDescriptionBox(itemImage, descriptionBox){
    var ii = itemImage;
    var db = descriptionBox;
    if(ii.attrs.x > db.x - 20 && ii.attrs.x < db.x + 20 && ii.attrs.y > db.y - 20 && ii.attrs.y < db.y +20){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

/* This function draws the game elements */
function drawGameElements(){
    /* Draw a line for the 'score bar'. */
    context.moveTo(0, 25);
    context.lineTo(1000, 25);
    context.stroke();

    /* Draw current level/ total levels on the left, and current score on the right. */
    context.font = "11pt Calibri"; /* Text font & size */
    context.strokeStyle = "black"; /* Font colour */
    context.strokeText(currentLevel + "/" + totalLevels, 10, 15);
    context.strokeText(currentScore, 750, 15);
}

function initStage(images){
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: "container",
        width: 1000,
        height: 500
    });
    var descriptionLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    //var imagesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var allImages = [];
    var currentScore = 0;

    var descriptionBoxes = {
        assetsDescriptionBox: {
            x: 70,
            y: 400
        },
        liabilitiesDescriptionBox: {
            x: 300,
            y: 400
        },
        incomeDescriptionBox: {
            x: 530,
            y: 400
        },
        expenditureDescriptionBox: {
            x: 760,
            y: 400
        },
    };

    /*Code to detect whether image has been dragged to correct description box */
    for (var key in sources){
        /*Anonymous function to induce scope */
        (function(){
            var privateKey = key;
            var imageSource = sources[key];

            /*Check if image has been dragged to the correct box, and add it to that box's
                array and remove from canvas if it has */
            canvasImage.on("dragend", function(){
                var descriptionBox = descriptionBoxes[privateKey];
                if(!canvasImage.inRightPlace && isNearDescriptionBox(itemImage, descriptionBox)){
                    context.remove(canvasImage);
                    /*Will need to add a line in here to add the image to the box's array */
                }
            })

        })();
    }

}

function drawImage(imageObj) {
    //var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var canvasImage = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: imageObj,
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      // puts the image in teh middle of the canvas
      x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 50 / 2,
      y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 50 / 2,
      draggable: true
    });

    // add cursor styling
    canvasImage.on('mouseover', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });
    canvasImage.on('mouseout', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    });

    imagesLayer.add(canvasImage);
}

/*This code loads the images to the canvas when the browser window loads */
window.onload = function(){
    var sources = {};
        sources[0] = document.getElementById("building").src,
        sources[1] = document.getElementById("chair").src,
        sources[2] = document.getElementById("drink").src,
        sources[3] = document.getElementById("food").src,
        sources[4] = document.getElementById("fridge").src,
        sources[5] = document.getElementById("land").src,
        sources[6] = document.getElementById("money").src,
        sources[7] = document.getElementById("oven").src,
        sources[8] = document.getElementById("table").src,
        sources[9] = document.getElementById("van").src,

        sources[10] = document.getElementById("burger").src,
        sources[11] = document.getElementById("chips").src,
        sources[12] = document.getElementById("drink").src,
        sources[13] = document.getElementById("franchiseFee").src,
        sources[14] = document.getElementById("wages").src,

        sources[15] = document.getElementById("admin").src,
        sources[16] = document.getElementById("cleaners").src,
        sources[17] = document.getElementById("electricity").src,
        sources[18] = document.getElementById("insurance").src,
        sources[19] = document.getElementById("manager").src,
        sources[20] = document.getElementById("rates").src,
        sources[21] = document.getElementById("training").src,
        sources[22] = document.getElementById("water").src,

        sources[23] = document.getElementById("burger").src,
        sources[24] = document.getElementById("chips").src,
        sources[25] = document.getElementById("drink").src,

        sources[26] = document.getElementById("creditors").src,
        sources[27] = document.getElementById("electricity").src,
        sources[28] = document.getElementById("food").src,
        sources[29] = document.getElementById("hirePurchase").src,
        sources[30] = document.getElementById("loan").src,
        sources[31] = document.getElementById("overdraft").src,
        sources[32] = document.getElementById("payeTax").src,
        sources[33] = document.getElementById("tax").src

    loadImages(sources, drawImage);
    drawGameElements();
    drawDescriptionBoxes();
};


</script>
```

The `window.onload()` function at the end is getting a load of images from a hidden section in the body of the HTML.

I have three JavaScript files that are being called in the HTML:

drawdescriptionboxes.js

```
function drawDescriptionBoxes(){
var assetsDescriptionBox = new Image();
var liabilitiesDescriptionBox = new Image();
var incomeDescriptionBox = new Image();
var expenditureDescriptionBox = new Image();
assetsDescriptionBox.src = 'images/box.png';
liabilitiesDescriptionBox.src = 'images/box.png';
incomeDescriptionBox.src = 'images/box.png';
expenditureDescriptionBox.src = 'images/box.png';

context.drawImage(assetsDescriptionBox, 70, 400, 120, 70);
context.drawImage(liabilitiesDescriptionBox, 300, 400, 120, 70);
context.drawImage(incomeDescriptionBox, 530, 400, 120, 70);
context.drawImage(expenditureDescriptionBox, 760, 400, 120, 70);

context.strokeText("Assets", 100, 490);
context.strokeText("Liabilities", 325, 490);
context.strokeText("Income", 550, 490);
context.strokeText("Expenditure", 775, 490);


}

function dragImageToBox(){

}
```

drawleveloneelements.js:

```
/* This function draws the elements for level 1. */
function drawLevelOneElements(){
    /*First, clear the canvas */ 
    context.clearRect(0, 0, myGameCanvas.width, myGameCanvas.height);
    /*This line clears all of the elements that were previously drawn on the canvas. */
    /*Then redraw the game elements */
    drawGameElements(); 
    /*Call the function to enable drag and drop */
    canvasState(document.getElementById('gameCanvas'));

    /*Create the four description areas, and place them near the bottom of the canvas */
    /*Create boxes with rounded corners for the description areas */
    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawDescriptionArea = function(x, y, width, height, radius, stroke){
        if(typeof stroke == "undefined" ){
            stroke = true;
        }
        if(typeof radius === "undefined"){
            radius = 5;
        }
        this.beginPath();
        this.moveTo(x + radius, y);
        this.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
        this.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
        this.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
        this.lineTo(x, y + radius);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
        this.closePath();
        if(stroke){
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

    context.drawDescriptionArea(70, 400, 120, 70);
    context.font = '25pt Calibri';
    context.strokeText('Asset', 90, 440);

    context.drawDescriptionArea(300, 400, 120, 70);
    context.strokeText('Liability', 310, 440);

    context.drawDescriptionArea(540, 400, 120, 70);
    context.strokeText('Income', 550, 440);

    context.drawDescriptionArea(750, 400, 180, 70);
    context.strokeText('Expenditure', 760, 440);

    /*Now draw the images to the canvas */
    /*First, create variables for the x & y coordinates of the image that will be drawn.
    the x & y coordinates should hold random numbers, so that the images will be 
    drawn in random locations on the canvas.*/
    var imageX = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    var imageY = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    var imageWidth = 50;
    var imageHeight = 50;

    /*Create a 'table' of positions that the images will be drawn to */
    var imagePositionsX = [20, 80, 140, 200, 260, 320, 380, 440, 500, 560];
    var imagePositionsY = [20, 60, 100, 140, 180, 220, 260, 300, 340, 380];

    /*Draw all images from assetsImageArray */
    /*Use a while loop to loop through the array, get each item and draw it. */
    var arrayIteration = 0;
    console.log('All Images Array length: ' + allImagesArray.length); /*Display the length of the array in the console, to check it's holding the correct number of images. */
    while(arrayIteration < allImagesArray.length){
        //var randomPositionX = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
        //var randomPositionY = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
        context.drawImage(allImagesArray[arrayIteration], imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight); /*Declare variables for image height and width, so it can be accessed elsewhere */
        //allImagesArray[arrayIteration].setDraggable = "true";
        allImagesArray[arrayIteration].setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
        console.log(arrayIteration); /*Display the current array position that's being drawn */
        arrayIteration = arrayIteration+1;
        /*Now try changing the values of imageX & imageY so that the next image is drawn to a 
        different location*/
        //imageX = imagePositionsX[randomPositionX];    /* imageX+(Math.floor(Math.random()*100)); */
        //imageY = imagePositionsY[randomPositionY];    /* imageY+(Math.floor(Math.random()*100));  */
        imageX = Math.floor(Math.random()*950);
        imageY = Math.floor(Math.random()*350);

    }

}
```

and startgamedrawgameelementsdrawstartbutton.js:

```
    /* Global variables */
var image = new Image();

/* This function starts the game, and calls all of the other functions required to play the game */
        function startGame(){
            preLoadImages();
        //  drawGameElements(); /*Remove this call from function startGame(), so that the score bar doesn't show while the start button is displayed */
            drawStartButton(); 

            /*Add event listener to the canvas, which will call drawLevelOneElements()
                when the start button is clicked*/
            myGameCanvas.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                console.log('click: ' + e.pageX + '/' + e.pageY);
                var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                if((mouseX > 260.5 && mouseX < 410.5+179) && (mouseY > 120 && mouseY < 120+180)){ /* Changing the '60' coordinates to 206 works for some reason */
                    drawLevelOneElements();
                    init();
                    /*Disable the event listener for clicking start button, because it continues to listen for a click */
                    this.removeEventListener('click',arguments.callee,false);
                } else {
                    console.log('no collision');
                }
            }, false);
        }

        /* This function draws the game elements */
        function drawGameElements(){

            /* Draw a line for the 'score bar'. */
            context.moveTo(0, 25);
            context.lineTo(1000, 25);
            context.stroke();

            /* Draw current level/ total levels on the left, and current score on the right. */
            context.font = "11pt Calibri"; /* Text font & size */
            context.strokeStyle = "black"; /* Font colour */
            context.strokeText(currentLevel + "/" + totalLevels, 10, 15);
            context.strokeText(currentScore, currentScorePositionX, currentScorePositionY);
        }

        /* This function draws a start button which the user can click to start the game */
        function drawStartButton(){
            image.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(image, 410.5, 120);
            };
            image.src = "startButton.png";
            /* Now I need to add an event listener to the area of the canvas on 
                on which the button image is displayed, in order to 'listen' for 
                a click on the button */
            var boundingBox = myGameCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            //var mouseX = (mouse_event.clientX-boundingBox.left) * (myGameCanvas.width/boundingBox.width);
            //var mouseY = (mouse_event.clientY-boundingBox.top) * (myGameCanvas.height/boundingBox.height);
            boundingBox.onmousemove = function(e){
                var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                var pixels = context.getImageData(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1);
            }               
        }
```

When I view the page in a browser by right clicking the file, and selecting 'open with Firefox', all of the images are displayed, and I'm able to drag and drop them around the canvas. However, when viewing the page at the URL at which I've located it, http://users.aber.ac.uk/eef8/project/development/dragimagestoboxes/ as soon as you click one of the images displayed, everything disappears from the canvas.

I can't figure out why this is, given that all the files I have saved locally are exactly the same as those saved on the server.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It would be helpful to reduce the amount of code you have in this to a small enough section to demonstrate the problem. Additionally if you are getting display anomalies, screenshots (or a jsfiddle!) are awesome tools to help communicate. That being said, you seem to be accessing files to do this. Loading with "open from disk" vs "open from network" provides entirely different access to resources.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 for [drawLevelOneElements.js](http://users.aber.ac.uk/eef8/project/development/dragimagestoboxes/drawLevelOneElements.js). Check your error console!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the console?

```
GET http://users.aber.ac.uk/eef8/project/development/dragimagestoboxes/drawLevelOneElements.js 404 (Not Found) users.aber.ac.uk:18
GET http://users.aber.ac.uk/eef8/project/development/dragimagestoboxes/images/startButton.png 404 (Not Found) users.aber.ac.uk:18
GET http://users.aber.ac.uk/eef8/project/development/dragimagestoboxes/images/liabilities/hirePurchase.jpg 404 (Not Found) users.aber.ac.uk:18
GET http://users.aber.ac.uk/eef8/project/development/dragimagestoboxes/images/liabilities/payeTax.jpg 404 (Not Found) users.aber.ac.uk:18
GET http://users.aber.ac.uk/eef8/project/development/dragimagestoboxes/images/expenses/direct/franchiseFee.jpg 404 (Not Found) users.aber.ac.uk:18
GET http://users.aber.ac.uk/eef8/project/development/dragimagestoboxes/images/liabilities/hirePurchase.jpg 404 (Not Found) users.aber.ac.uk:62
GET http://users.aber.ac.uk/eef8/project/development/dragimagestoboxes/images/expenses/direct/franchiseFee.jpg 404 (Not Found) users.aber.ac.uk:62
GET http://users.aber.ac.uk/eef8/project/development/dragimagestoboxes/images/liabilities/payeTax.jpg 404 (Not Found) users.aber.ac.uk:62
```

Looks like you forgot to upload some files.

Comment: In the console, I get a printout for each time an image is added to the array- as I wanted, but I then get a few lines with the error: `NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component is not available
[Break On This Error]  

context.drawImage(a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);` which is complaining about a line in the kineticJS library. I have saved a local copy of the kineticJS library and am using that, as there were one or two chanages I needed to make to some of the functionality it provided.

Comment: Upload all of the missing files. They are not there. When they are there, see if your errors magically go away.

Comment: I think I see why you're getting those errors though- the server is Unix based, and must have converted those capitals to lowercase in the filenames

Comment: I've changed the references in the file to all lowercase, but I'm still having the problem described in my original post

Comment: I cleared the cache and I still see all of the files being requested with the camel case.

Comment: Ok- I tried renaming the files again, and that seems to have solved the issue- thanks very much!